# declval expression (for SFINAE) with std::ostream

Tags: c++, sfinae

I'm trying to create a type traits class to determine if a particular type `T` can be streamed via the `<<` operator of an `std::ostream`.  I'm using a straightforward SFINAE technique.

Ultimately, the expression I attempt to evaluate for substitution failure is:

```
decltype(std::declval<std::ostream>() << std::declval<T>()) ;
```

My expectation is that, given an instance `t` of type `T` and an `std::ostream` instance `os`, if the expression  `os << t` is ill-formed, a substitution failure should occur.

But apparently substitution failure never occurs here regardless of the type `T`.  And even if I just declare a `typedef` using the above `decltype` expression, outside the context of SFINAE, it happily compiles, even if `T` cannot be used with `std::ostream`.

For example:

```
struct Foo  { };

int main()
{
    // This compiles fine using GCC 4.9.2
    //
    typedef decltype(
        std::declval<std::ostream>() << std::declval<Foo>()
    ) foo_type;
}
```

The above will compile fine using GCC 4.9.2, which is not what I expected since the `<<` operator is not overloaded to work with a type `Foo`.  And of course, if I say:

```
std::cout << Foo();
```

... I get a compiler error.  So why does the `decltype` expression above even compile at all?

Comment: It reacts correctly with `std::declval<std::ostream&>()`. But I have no idea why.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

C++11 added the following `operator<<` overload:

```
template< class CharT, class Traits, class T >
basic_ostream< CharT, Traits >& operator<<( basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>&& os, 
                                            const T& value );
```

This forwards on to the standard insertion operators, which can't bind rvalue references to `std::ostream`s because they take non-const references. Since `std::declval<std::ostream>` returns `std::ostream&&`, this overload is selected, then due to the very permissive interface (i.e. this isn't SFINAEd out if there is no valid underlying insertion operator), your `decltype` specifier works.

The simple fix is to use `std::declval<std::ostream&>()`. This will return a `std::ostream&`, so the template overload will not be selected by your `decltype` specifier and a normal insertion operator overload will be required for it to compile:

```
typedef decltype(
    std::declval<std::ostream&>() << std::declval<Foo>()
) foo_type;
```

Clang outputs this:

```
main.cpp:8:39: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('std::basic_ostream<char>' and 'Foo')
        std::declval<std::ostream&>() << std::declval<Foo>()
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

[<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d9bf5bca68b3b2a0)

---

Here's a simpler example which exhibits the same problem:

```
#include <string>

void foo (int&,int){}
void foo (int&,float){}

template <typename T>
void foo (int&& a, T b) {
    foo(a, b);
}

int main()
{
    std::string s;
    typedef decltype(foo(1,s)) foo_type;
}
```

[<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/64e3d642d25773d6)

---

Here are the relevant standards quotes (N4140):

The declaration must be instantiated because overload resolution is involved:

> `[temp.inst]/10:` If a function template or a member function template specialization is used in a way that involves overload
>   resolution, a declaration of the specialization is implicitly instantiated (14.8.3).

Only the declaration needs to be instantiated:

> `[temp.over]/5:` Only the signature of a function template specialization is needed to enter the specialization in a set of
>   candidate functions. Therefore only the function template declaration is needed to resolve a call for which
>   a template specialization is a candidate.

And the implementation is not allowed to instantiate the function body:

> `[temp.inst]/11:` An implementation shall not implicitly instantiate a function template, a variable template, a member template, a non-virtual member function, a member class, or a static data member of a class template that does not require instantiation.

Comment: Why does your simpler example exhibit the problem? (i.e., why isn't it a substitution failure?)

Comment: @Eric I mean it wouldn't be a substitution failure in any case because it's not in an SFINAE context, but it's not a hard failure because the `decltype` specifier is an unevaluated context, so only the declaration is instantiated.

Comment: @Eric I added the relevant standards quotes, is that clearer?

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't really answer why this is happening but if you replace with `std::stream&` as below:

```
template<typename T, typename Enable = std::ostream&>
struct can_be_streamed : std::false_type {};
template<typename T>
struct can_be_streamed<T, 
         decltype(std::declval<std::ostream&>() << std::declval<T>())> : std::true_type {};
```

seems to work.

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/abddc0a873804362)

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the header file `ostream`, you will find that because `std::declval` produces rvlaue references, there is actually a matching generic `operator<<`:

```
#if __cplusplus >= 201103L
  /** 
   *  @brief  Generic inserter for rvalue stream
   *  @param  __os  An input stream.
   *  @param  __x  A reference to the object being inserted.
   *  @return  os  
   *   
   *  This is just a forwarding function to allow insertion to
   *  rvalue streams since they won't bind to the inserter functions
   *  that take an lvalue reference.
  */  
  template<typename _CharT, typename _Traits, typename _Tp>
    inline basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&
    operator<<(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&& __os, const _Tp& __x)
    {   
      __os << __x;
      return __os;
    }   
#endif // C++11
```

This explains why you get no substition failure. However, this can't actually be matched against the `std::cout << Foo()` call. Here is the relevant part of the compilation error:

```
/usr/local/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.1.0/../../../../include/c++/6.1.0/ostream:628:5: note: candidate function [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Tp = Foo] not viable: no known conversion from 'ostream' (aka 'basic_ostream<char>') to 'basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > &&' for 1st argument
    operator<<(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&& __os, const _Tp& __x)
    ^
```

The problem here is that the lhs can only be an rvalue reference, but you're (obviously) using an lvalue (i.e. `std::cout`) in the call.